# How to save a DateField on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, datefield

I create a DateField and add it on screen1 like above image.
User can select "time" from this DateField.
I want to save this "time" and create a new DateField has a same "time" on screen2

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DateField.getDate()` and `DateField.setDate()` methods for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help but If I use DateField.getDate() it will return a long type. How can  i can get this long type on a new class screen becasue Persistent Object can not save data with long type.

Comment: To store a `long` value in a `PersistentObject`, put it inside an instance of the `Long` class.  `PersistentObject` supports `Long` objects.